# TableView reloadData() not showing all data, even though the array with values is filled (swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, tableview, reloaddata

I have a tableview that I fill with results from an http call. The data is passed on into the array called `tripTimes`. `triptimes` contains information about certain trips made during a given day. The starting time of every trip of that day is passed into `self.tableData` and is inserted into the tableView.

After this, I reload the table and... strange results.

The array `tableData` gets filled properly, but after I call `self.tableView.reloadData()` almost all cells are properly filled. However, the first cell is left empty until I tap it or if I wait for about 5 seconds and the last cell is also empty, but it gets the same value as the first cell after the same time.

I think it has to do something with the `dispatch_async` part, but I'm fairly new to swift and iOS, so I have no clue where to look. When I print the contents of `self.tableData` inside the `dispatch_async` function, the array contains the proper values.

Below is the code for my viewController

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SwiftHTTP
class TripSelect: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func showTrips(sender: AnyObject) {

        //if data is already present in tableData, empty it first
        if self.tripTimes.count != 0 && self.tableData.count != 0 {
            for var i=0; i<self.tripTimes.count; i++ {
                self.tableData.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
                let indexPathToRemove = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathToRemove], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        var request = HTTPTask()
        request.GET("<MY_URL>", parameters: ["date": dateTextField.text], success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
            if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {

                let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
                let str2 = "\"not enough data for this day\""

                if str != str2 {
                    let json:AnyObject = JSON.parse(str)

                    self.dayLatLongs = json["dayLatLongs"] as Array
                    self.tripTimes = json["tripTimes"] as Array

                    var tripLatLongs:[AnyObject] = self.dayLatLongs[0] as Array
                    var firstTrip:[AnyObject] = tripLatLongs[0] as Array
                    var tripStartTime:String = ""
                    for var i=0; i<self.tripTimes.count; i++ {
                        tripStartTime = self.tripTimes[i]["startTime"] as String
                        //println("\(tripStartTime)")
                        self.tableData.addObject(tripStartTime)
                        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        println(self.tableData)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                } else {println(str)}
            }
            },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
                println("error: \(error)")
        })
    }

    var dayLatLongs:[AnyObject] = []
    var tripTimes:[AnyObject] = []
    var tableData: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableData.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = backgroundView
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

UPDATE:

```
var indexPaths:[NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath]()
for var i=0; i<self.tripTimes.count; i++ {
    tripStartTime = self.tripTimes[i]["startTime"] as String
    self.tableData.addObject(tripStartTime)
    indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
}
self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Now the results are shown properly, but only after I 'drag' the table a couple of times.

Comment: The `success` block is most likely running on the main thread anyway as the `showTrips` seems to be called on the main thread. There's no need to use `reloadData`  after  `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and  `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, but you need to make sure that the cells are inserted and removed with the correct indexes and only on the main thread: try to fill in the array with all indexes and make a single insert/remove call to make the process easier.

Comment: Ok, I tried something else (updated my question), so the values are shown correctly now, but only after I 'drag' the table a couple of times.

Comment: Try to do the same for the delete methods, as for the threads: you seem to ensure only the calls to `reloadData` to be on the main thread, do the same for insert/remove calls: they are very similar to `reloadData` in that sense and should be always called on the main thread. The  `reloadData` calls might be removed in this case as the table gets updated automatically and you'll probably mess up the animation.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the problem :) The animation shows properly now as well, very nice! I will post an answer, so it's easier to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to @A-Live for this answer.

Updated with suggested changes:

To remove cells, I changed the function to

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    if self.tripTimes.count != 0 && self.tableData.count != 0 {
        self.tableData = []
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(self.indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        self.indexPaths = []
    }
})
```

To add cells, I changed the function to

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    for var i=0; i<self.tripTimes.count; i++ {
        tripStartTime = self.tripTimes[i]["startTime"] as String
        self.tableData.addObject(tripStartTime)
        self.indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
    }
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(self.indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
})
```

Comment: Glad it worked, one last touch: make sure that you modify datasource on the same thread to make all update operations thread safe. In this case move the loop and `tableData = []` inside the GCD blocks that you already have. Otherwise it is possible that consequent calls to `showTrips` try to modify the same array (datasource in general) on (possibly) different detached threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the first if-clause:

```
 if self.tripTimes.count != 0 && self.tableData.count != 0 {
            for var i=0; i<self.tripTimes.count; i++ {
                self.tableData.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
                let indexPathToRemove = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathToRemove], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
```

You always remove just the value at index `0` and you don't use the `i`. So replace all hardcoded `0` with your index `i`:

```
 if self.tripTimes.count != 0 && self.tableData.count != 0 {
            for var i=0; i<self.tripTimes.count; i++ {
                self.tableData.removeObjectAtIndex(i)
                let indexPathToRemove = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathToRemove], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, allthough that's not the problem. When I fill the table for the first time, the program doesn't execute that part of the code, because `self.tripTimes.count` and `self.tableData.count` are both 0 at that point (I checked with println)